# what is default http method in rest web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

Is there any default method for java restful web services.
If I dont annotate my root resource class method with any html method annotation then will it match the upcoming get request to that method

```
@Path("xyz")
class abc 
{
 String  methodName(String name)
 {
  //processing 
 }

}
```

In this case if I have an get request , then will this method be treated as resource . 
I read that when our resource methods are annotated with @Path and not with @AnyHttpMehtod then its a sub resource locator. I want to know when we dont have any http method annotation then will there be some default behavior.

Comment: Did you try what happened?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

By default, the JAX-RS runtime will automatically support the methods HEAD and OPTIONS if not explicitly implemented. For HEAD, the runtime will invoke the implemented GET method, if present, and ignore the response entity, if set. For OPTIONS, the Allow response header will be set to the set of HTTP methods supported by the resource. In addition, the JAX-RS runtime will return a Web Application Definition Language (WADL) document describing the resource; see https://wadl.dev.java.net/ for more information.

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giepu/index.html)